# Incorporate an icon to python .exe using py2exe

Tags: python, py2exe

I have this  **setup.py** script for incorporating icon for my .exe file, 
but the icon isnt appearing after the setup. 
the icon is 361 KB in size.

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(
    console = [
        {
            "script": "wykoRas_parser.py",                    ### Main Python script    
            "icon_resources": [(0, "bw-gears.ico")]     ### Icon to embed into the PE file.
        }
    ],
)
```

Am i missing something from the setup?

Answer (score 1):

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(
    options = {'py2exe': {'bundle_files': 1}},
    zipfile = None,
    windows = [{
            "script":"myprogram.pyw",
            "icon_resources": [(1, "myicon.ico")],
            "dest_base":"myprogram"
            }],
)
```

Could you try this one please, I had some problem before these codes solved.

Comment: @ellabells I don't know what methods doing in `setup`, it's just solved my problem before.

Comment: An error? How, it worked for me before. Which Python version do you using?

Comment: i added import py2exe and it compiled, the problem is there's no icon and the .exe file isnt running, im using 2.7.3

Comment: @ellabells The problem about exe file isn't running, probably about your program not setup. I think your icon is have problems, could you try another icons? And check your main script again, if exe isn't running then something wrong in your main script.

Comment: the main script is working fine without the additional code from the icon. My icon is now 1KB in size and 16x16 pix @importV

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, apparently is an old bug that hasn't been fixed. I found a workaround though.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29007820/exe-icon-doesnt-change-py2exe/36116599#36116599) solved the issue for me, look for Ronan Paixão answer