# .exe Icon Doesn't Change [py2exe]

Tags: python, python-2.7, icons, py2exe

My icon file myicon.ico in same directory with setup.py. When I run py2exe, myproject.exe doesn't have icon. I looked for solution but couldn't find.

setup.py code is:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(
   windows=[{
         "script": "myproject.py",
         "icon_resources": [(0, "favicon.ico")],
      }]
)
```

OS: Win8.1 64bit

Comment: Last I had a problem like this (ages ago, 32bit), I ended up using an external tool to change the icon. Extra points for creating a link in your installer and changing the icon on the link itself rather than on executable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears py2exe has [a 4-year-old bug on handling icons](https://sourceforge.net/p/py2exe/bugs/124/), but due to its description, I managed to make this workaround:

```
setup_dict = dict(
    windows = [{'script': "script.py",
                "icon_resources": [(1, "icon.ico")}],
)

setup(**setup_dict)
setup(**setup_dict)
```

This pretty much builds the project twice. If your project is complex and takes too long to process through py2exe, you can use this to build a dummy py file:

```
import tempfile
tf = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
tf.close()
setup(
    windows = [{
        'script': tf.name,
        "icon_resources":[(1, "icon.ico")]}]
)
os.remove(tf.name)
```

Just don't forget to set excludes like your project, otherwise you will get your `dist` folder cluttered with unwanted files.

Comment: This worked for me. The first call to `setup()` does not result in an icon but all the subsequent ones do. So, the dummy `.py` file needs to be used on the first call to `setup()`. Similar solution has also been reported [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/py2exe/mailman/message/34169215/).

Comment: Excellent! This fixes the problem for me. The embedded icon files wouldn't render above the 48x48 layer, but now they do.

Answer (score 3):

Please try this

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(
    options = {'py2exe': {'bundle_files': 1}},
    zipfile = None,
    windows = [{
            "script":"myproject.py",
            "icon_resources": [(1, "favicon.ico")],
            }],
)
```

Comment: When I try this, it says "bundle-files 1 is not yet supported on win64". If I delete "options = {'py2exe': {'bundle_files': 1}},", icon doesn't change. If I use 32bit system to be able to use bundle_files:1, does it work in 64bit systems ? Or do you have another recommend ? Thanks for answer.

Comment: I had same issue once for 64. But i forget it. I will find it in my old project code. You can vote up for 32-bit windows.

Comment: I have just tried the code in 32bit system, it works without any bundle_files:1 problem but icon didn't change! Is problem may be about icon file ? I tried 256x256 & 64x64 .ico images.

Answer (score 2):

I handled my problem like that;

1. I used the above code which I post in my question.
2. Then I installed [Resourch Hacker](http://angusj.com/resourcehacker/) program.
3. I opened myprogram.exe file with Resourch Hacker program.
4. Then Action > Replace Icon > I choosed the icon which I want.
5. And its ok!

For Resourch Hacker tutorial [CLICK THIS](http://www.howtogeek.com/75983/stupid-geek-tricks-how-to-modify-the-icon-of-an-.exe-file/)

Comment: Even I found the solution, it can be better if someone know to do it directly by py2exe.

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same problem. I have solved it by download a win7 icon from http://www.iconarchive.com/search?q=windows+7&page=5, and the reason should be the icon file that could not work at the very start is not a correct win7 format icon.

this web page https://www.creativefreedom.co.uk/icon-designers-blog/windows-7-icon-sizes/ tells us a topic "Testing your Windows 7 Icon" to check whether a icon is a really win7 icon.

Answer (score 0):

I used a different program, came accross pyinstaller [from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42292103/1445985)
and it worked first time.

Installed it:

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

Compiled my program:

```
pyinstaller myprogram.py -i icon.ico
```

Worked first time! Hope that helps.